# Dual booting linux with windows 10

Tags: ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu version 16.04.03 with dual boot on my Windows 10.For this I partitioned my C drive and allocated 50 gb space for ubuntu and I used rufus.

Ubuntu installed completely but when I restarted my PC I was **unable to choose between Ubuntu and Windows**.

My keyboard stops responding, but if I plug my pendrive I'm able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows (keyboard responds while pendrive is plugged in).

Comment: With no pendrive, what is displayed on the screen?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like grub got installed on the USB flash drive instead of on your computer's hard drive. Boot from the Ubuntu live USB flash drive, select *Try Ubuntu without installing*, and open the Disks application to find out on which disk Ubuntu is installed. In Disks select the disk on which Ubuntu is installed and after where it says *Device* there will appear the location of the partition in the selected disk which contains the root filesystem of Ubuntu which is installed on that disk, which I will call `/dev/sda1` in this example although it may be different in your computer.

Open the terminal and run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

This command will install grub to the MBR of the first hard drive, which should make it bootable. Before you boot to Ubuntu again, remember to set the hard drive where grub is installed to boot first in the BIOS/UEFI boot sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common scenario and doesn't require much effort to fix. Your `grub` needs a repair (most likely it got installed in your live USB) in order to the `grub` menu to show up during the booting of your system. You can do it in two ways:

1. Traditional way - Manually install `grub` (as mentioned in karel's answer here) and edit the `grub` configuration file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (only if you really have to), if needed, to point to the right partition.
2. Use a third-party boot repair program like `boot-repair` mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) or `grub-customizer` mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order).

Cheers & Good Luck!